# Adding conditional statements to custom text fields in views

Tags: views, entities

I have custom text fields set to display two items as follows:

> [field_title]: [field_subtitle]

Is there a way I can get rid of the colon if the subtitle field has no value? via php or javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

1. Edit both fields -- `[field_title]` *and* `[field_subtitle]` -- so that both are "exluded from display"
2. Edit `[field_subtitle]`, and select *Rewrite the output of this field*

   1. In the box for the rewritten value, enter `: [field_subtitle]`
   2. Make sure *Hide rewriting if empty* is checked at the bottom
3. Create a third field whose type is *Global: custom text*

   1. Unlike the first two existing fields, do **not** check the *Exclude from display* box -- leave this one visible
   2. In the *Text* box for that field (the value), enter `[field_title][field_subtitle]` (no spaces in between)

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: Is there a way we can scale it if there are more than two tokens that needs to be displayed like this.